# How to display user data after he logs in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to display the users info when he selects View Profile. How can I do this as im new to mvc. Links to help or an explanation will help a lot. Thanks

Here is my Login Action:

```
public ActionResult Authorize(The_Pizzatorium.Models.tblUser userModel)
    {
        using (The_PizzatoriumEntities1 db = new The_PizzatoriumEntities1())
        {
            var userDetails = db.tblUsers.Where(x => x.dUSerName == userModel.dUSerName && x.dPassword == userModel.dPassword).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password.";
                return View("Index", userModel);
            }


            else
            {
                Session["UserID"] = userDetails.dID;
                Session["userName"] = userDetails.dUSerName;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
    }
```

How will I need to make the View Profile Action to display the logged in Users Details?

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: `x.dPassword == userModel.dPassword` It is a **very bad idea** to store passwords directly in a database. Is there a particular reason you aren't using the inbuilt Forms Authentication functionality?

Comment: thanks for feedback. Still new and still got a lot to learn

Comment: Did not know there was that until recently so I am trying to adapt my code I currently have

Answer (score 0):

when user come to viewprofile action check use session

```
    public ActionResult ViewProfile()
        { 
    if(Session["UserID"]!=null)
    {
//check user uid datatype 
//then store in variable
int useesionid=COnvert.toint32(Session["UserID"].tosting())

    var userDetails = db.tblUsers.Where(x => x.uid==useesionid).ToList();
    ///here your code
            return View( userDetails );
        }
```

Comment: I am getting an error that operator == cannot be applied to type Int and method group,adn on the action name that not all code paths return a value

Comment: Still getting that not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, to get the user details if logged in other wise redirecting to login page.

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile()
{
    if(Session["UserID"] != null)
    {
        using (The_PizzatoriumEntities1 db = new The_PizzatoriumEntities1())
        {
            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());

            var userDetails = db.tblUsers.Where(x => x.dID == userId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userDetails != null)
            {
                return View(userDetails);
            }
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account"); // Redirect to your login page
}
```